# Read multiple .tsv files in a loop in R

Tags: r

I am working on simplifying my script and would like to use some for loops. Right now I am reading in the following five .tsv files independently. I would like to write a loop which reads each one and assigns it a variable name in sequential order starting from 2008 and ending in 2012. These files are saved in a folder that contains other files that are not important for this step. Any ideas? Thank you.

```
t2008 <- read.table(file = './T2008.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
t2009 <- read.table(file = './T2010.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
t2011 <- read.table(file = './T2009.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
t2010 <- read.table(file = './T2011.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
t2012 <- read.table(file = './T2012.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `assign` is our friend here:

```r
years <- 2008:2012
variable_names <- paste0("T", years)

for(i in variable_names){
  filename <- paste0('./', i, ".tsv")
  dat <- read.table(file = filename, sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
  assign(i, dat)
}
```

While I can't test this exact code without access to your files, here's what I did to test it:

```r
years <- 2008:2012
variable_names <- paste0("T", years)

for(i in variable_names){
  filename <- paste0('./', i, ".tsv")
  dat <- filename
  assign(i, dat)
}
```

which produces five new objects in my global environment, T2008 through T2012, with the expected values: "./T2008.tsv", "./T2009.tsv", etc.

Comment: This does not even work as i is rewritten during each iteration. What you really want is `res = list()` and `res[[filename]] = dat`

Comment: @Colombo I don't think that's correct - R is smart enough to assign the *value* of i rather than assigning "i" each time. I wasn't able to test it with the OP's files, but see my edit for the test output I got.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! I figured out a solution which worked for me. I'll post it here for others with similiar issues:

```{r}
all_files <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(c(2008:2012)) )
ite_input <- 1
sum_nrow1 <- 0



for (i in c(2008:2012)) {
  filename <- paste("T", i , ".tsv", sep = "")
  all_files[[ite_input]] <- read.table(file = filename, sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
  sum_nrow1 <- sum_nrow1 + nrow(all_files[[ite_input]])
  ite_input <- ite_input + 1

}
```

Comment: @Dubukay oh, sorry, I try to avoid `assign` as much as I can so I am not that familiar with its usage (and misread the docu). Still, I think its bad solution and one should save it to list to avoid side-effect. Files can be then easily merged (if they share the same format) with `do.call(rbind, list)`.

Comment: @Colombo Agreed, it's certainly not how I'd do it and it looks like OP found that to be a better solution in the end but I always try to give the asked-for answer when possible!